read xml content of the workbook when file is opened
I am trying to find out if it is possible to parse and modify the underlining xml file of a workbook upon closing it. In my close_workbook event I would like to be able to read the xml file and modify some of the content. All the examples I see online are for reading the xml file when it is extracted from the xslx file which is not what I need.
Does anyone have any experience with it ?
TIA
read and write to the underlining xml data file when workbook is closed/open

What exactly are you wanting to change about the workbook which can't be changed via the typical non-XML methods?

I need to make a change to the formulas without triggering/recalculate them. I am hoping to find a way to do this when workbook is being closed.

You can modify the workbook while it is read-only.  Here is a simply demo code that will delete the file while it is open.
Sub DeleteThisWorkbook()
    ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
    Kill ThisWorkbook.FullName
End Sub

We could modify the underlying xml file of the workbook while it is read-only, but I think we'll have to reopen it to see any changes. You should expect some spooky behavior .Let me know what happens.

sorry, but I don't understand how this example helps me access the underlying xml file while the workbook is open. the read only part makes sense to me.

The example is the ultimate demonstration of modifying a file while its open...lol.  FYI,  I was looking into reading the xml  a couple of days ago and could not find a native way of doing it without unzipping the file.  It's doable by shelling Power Script but than the Power Script window always wants  to stay open.  Please, let me know if you figure something out.
